# Minor Version on libgcc_s.so.1 on Linux

Tags: linux, version, dynamic-library

I have noticed that on SLES SP1 and Ubuntu 10.04 they only have a major version of libgcc_s in `/lib64`. However on RHEL 6.1 they have the major version point to a minor version with the date appended to the minor version of the library. I need the minor version for a matrix I am providing to customer support. How do you obtain the minor version of libgcc in both Ubuntu and SLES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is to just rebuild on the other systems. Failing that, extract the tarball from the gcc SRPM and then use the commands in the spec file to rebuild it.

Comment: I can do this on SLES since it is just rpm -ivh from the install DVD on that given srpm. How do I go about doing this for Ubuntu? Not very familiar with the debian packaging system?

Comment: @Matthew: You'll need to use `rpm` (which is available for Debian/Ubuntu, just not used for packaging) or `rpm2cpio` to extract it.